# How does instagram image gallery works?

Tags: javascript, image, instagram, gallery

I know there's one div:

```
<span id="react-root"></span>
```

Where it puts all the information (images, description, comments, etc) and there's a huge script below it with some photos (the first twelve of the user's profile you are looking at).

My question is:

> How does it work?

I'm using python to get the links from my photos so i can download all of them but no matter what i do, it always gives me the first twelve photos. Always. I guess it's because i'm using the source code of my profile and it does not refresh the page content.

Can anyone help me to understand instagram's image gallery system

How can I get the URLS to all the photos on my profile?

PD: Sorry for my bad english, i'm trying so hard right now...

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out Instagram's [API endpoints](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/) . You will need to create an access token if you want to fetch photos. 
BTW, the `react-root` id means they are using React.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i didn't know about this API, either way, is there any react documentation (or any documentation at all) about that gallery system? It's quite interesting and i will like to know more about it, not just to get my python programn done, but to implement it on future web-projects.